# transactional unit testing with ObjectifyService - no rollback happening

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We are trying to use google cloud datastore in our project and trying to use objectify as the ORM since google recommends it. I have carefully used and tried everything i could read about and think of but somehow the transactions don't seem to work. Following is my code and setup.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CoreTestConfiguration.class })
public class TestObjectifyTransactionAspect {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            // Our tests assume strong consistency
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy(),
            new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig(), new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig());

    private Closeable closeableSession;

    @Autowired
    private DummyService dummyService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        // Reset the Factory so that all translators work properly.
        ObjectifyService.setFactory(new ObjectifyFactory());
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8081");
        ObjectifyService.register(UserEntity.class);
        this.closeableSession = ObjectifyService.begin();
        this.helper.setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        AsyncCacheFilter.complete();
        this.closeableSession.close();
        this.helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransactionMutationRollback() {
        // save initial list of users
        List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
            user.setAge(i);
            user.setUsername("username_" + i);
            users.add(user);
        }
        ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entities(users).now();

        try {
             dummyService.mutateDataWithException("username_1", 6L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<UserEntity> users2 = this.dummyService.findAllUsers();  

        Assert.assertEquals("Size mismatch on rollback", users2.size(), 10);

        boolean foundUserIdSix = false;
        for (UserEntity userEntity : users2) {
            if (userEntity.getUserId() == 1) {
                Assert.assertEquals("Username update failed in transactional context rollback.", "username_1",
                        userEntity.getUsername());
            }
            if (userEntity.getUserId() == 6) {
                foundUserIdSix = true;
            }
        }

        if (!foundUserIdSix) {
            Assert.fail("Deleted user with userId 6 but it is not rolledback.");
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am using spring, idea is to use an aspect with a custom annotation to weave `objectify.transact` around the spring service beans methods that are calling my daos.
But somehow the update due to `ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entities(users).now();` is not gettign rollbacked though the exception throws causes Objectify to run its rollback code. I tried printing the ObjectifyImpl instance hashcodes and they are all same but still its not rollbacking.

Can someone help me understand what am i doing wrong? Havent tried the actual web based setup yet...if it cant pass transnational test cases there is no point in actual transaction usage in a web request scenario.

**Update:** Adding aspect, services, dao as well to make a complete picture. The code uses spring boot.

DAO class. Note i am not using any transactions here because as per code of `com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TransactorNo.transactOnce(ObjectifyImpl<O>, Work<R>)` a transnational `ObjectifyImpl` is flushed and committed in this method which i don't want. I want commit to happen once and rest all to join in on that transaction. Basically this is the wrong code in `com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TransactorNo` ..... i will try to explain my understanding a later in the question.

```
@Component
public class DummyDaoImpl implements DummyDao {

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> loadAll() {
        Query<UserEntity> query = ObjectifyService.ofy().transactionless().load().type(UserEntity.class);
        return query.list();
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> findByUserId(Long userId) {
        Query<UserEntity> query = ObjectifyService.ofy().transactionless().load().type(UserEntity.class);
        //query = query.filterKey(Key.create(UserEntity.class, userId));
        return query.list();
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> findByUsername(String username) {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy().transactionless().load().type(UserEntity.class).filter("username", username).list();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(UserEntity userEntity) {
        ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(userEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Iterable<UserEntity> userEntities) {
        ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entities(userEntities);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long userId) {
        ObjectifyService.ofy().delete().key(Key.create(UserEntity.class, userId));
    }
}
```

Below is the Service class

```
@Service
public class DummyServiceImpl implements DummyService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private DummyDao dummyDao;

    public void saveDummydata() {
        List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
            user.setAge(i);
            user.setUsername("username_" + i);
            users.add(user);
        }
        this.dummyDao.update(users);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.bbb.core.objectify.test.services.DummyService#mutateDataWithException(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long)
     */
    @Override
    @ObjectifyTransactional
    public void mutateDataWithException(String usernameToMutate, Long userIdToDelete) throws Exception {
        //update one
        LOGGER.info("Attempting to update UserEntity with username={}", "username_1");
        List<UserEntity> mutatedUsersList = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
        List<UserEntity> users = dummyDao.findByUsername(usernameToMutate);
        for (UserEntity userEntity : users) {
            userEntity.setUsername(userEntity.getUsername() + "_updated");
            mutatedUsersList.add(userEntity);
        }
        dummyDao.update(mutatedUsersList);

        //delete another
        UserEntity user = dummyDao.findByUserId(userIdToDelete).get(0);
        LOGGER.info("Attempting to delete UserEntity with userId={}", user.getUserId());
        dummyDao.delete(user.getUserId());
        throw new RuntimeException("Dummy Exception");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.bbb.core.objectify.test.services.DummyService#findAllUsers()
     */
    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> findAllUsers() {
        return dummyDao.loadAll();
    }
```

Aspect which wraps the method annoted with `ObjectifyTransactional` as a transact work.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ObjectifyTransactionAspect {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectifyTransactionAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(objectifyTransactional)")
    public Object objectifyTransactAdvise(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ObjectifyTransactional objectifyTransactional) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Object result = null;
            Work<Object> work = new Work<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object run() {
                    try {
                        return pjp.proceed();
                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                        throw new ObjectifyTransactionExceptionWrapper(throwable);
                    }
                }
            };

            switch (objectifyTransactional.propagation()) {
            case REQUIRES_NEW:
                int limitTries = objectifyTransactional.limitTries();
                if(limitTries <= 0) {
                    Exception illegalStateException = new IllegalStateException("limitTries must be more than 0.");
                    throw new ObjectifyTransactionExceptionWrapper(illegalStateException);
                } else {
                    if(limitTries == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        result = ObjectifyService.ofy().transactNew(work);
                    } else {
                        result = ObjectifyService.ofy().transactNew(limitTries, work);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NOT_SUPPORTED :
            case NEVER :
            case MANDATORY :
                result = ObjectifyService.ofy().execute(objectifyTransactional.propagation(), work);
                break;
            case REQUIRED :
            case SUPPORTS :
                ObjectifyService.ofy().transact(work);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return result;
        } catch (ObjectifyTransactionExceptionWrapper e) {
            String packageName = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
            String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
            LOGGER.error("An exception occured while executing [{}.{}] in a transactional context."
                                , packageName, methodName, e);
            throw e.getCause();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            String packageName = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
            String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
            String fullyQualifiedmethodName = packageName + "." + methodName;
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception while executing [" 
                                            + fullyQualifiedmethodName + "] in a transactional context.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem code part that i see is as follows in `com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TransactorNo`:

```
@Override
public <R> R transact(ObjectifyImpl<O> parent, Work<R> work) {
    return this.transactNew(parent, Integer.MAX_VALUE, work);
}

@Override
public <R> R transactNew(ObjectifyImpl<O> parent, int limitTries, Work<R> work) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(limitTries >= 1);

    while (true) {
        try {
            return transactOnce(parent, work);
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex) {
            if (--limitTries > 0) {
                if (log.isLoggable(Level.WARNING))
                    log.warning("Optimistic concurrency failure for " + work + " (retrying): " + ex);

                if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST))
                    log.log(Level.FINEST, "Details of optimistic concurrency failure", ex);
            } else {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}

private <R> R transactOnce(ObjectifyImpl<O> parent, Work<R> work) {
    ObjectifyImpl<O> txnOfy = startTransaction(parent);
    ObjectifyService.push(txnOfy);

    boolean committedSuccessfully = false;
    try {
        R result = work.run();
        txnOfy.flush();
        txnOfy.getTransaction().commit();
        committedSuccessfully = true;
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (txnOfy.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            try {
                txnOfy.getTransaction().rollback();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Rollback failed, suppressing error", ex);
            }
        }

        ObjectifyService.pop();

        if (committedSuccessfully) {
            txnOfy.getTransaction().runCommitListeners();
        }
    }
}
```

transactOnce is by code / design always using a single transaction to do things. It will either commit or rollback the transaction. there is no provision to chain transactions like a normal enterprise app would want.... service -> calls multiple dao methods in a single transaction and commits or rollbacks depending on how things look.

keeping this in mind, i removed all annotations and transact method calls in my dao methods so that they don't start an explicit transaction and the aspect in service wraps the service method in transact and ultimately in transactOnce...so basically the service method is running in a transaction and no new transaction is getting fired again. This is a very basic scenario, in actual production apps services can call other service methods and they might have the annotation on them and we could still end up in a chained transaction..but anyway...that is a different problem to solve....

I know NoSQLs dont support write consistency at table or inter table levels so am I asking too much from google cloud datastore?

Comment: I don't see a transaction here. Do you mean to use `ObjectifyService.transact()` instead of `ObjectifyService.run()`?

Comment: adding the aspect code....to make things clear...

Comment: @stickfigure: added all the code...please let me know if anything else is needed to understand the test flow.

Comment: I still don't see any transactions in your test code. Looks like you're saving data outside of a transaction. I don't understand how any of the rest of the code matters?

Comment: Look at the aspect.....its using the work instance inside a transact method. The aspect is weaved around any method that is annotated with objectifyTransactional. That method runs in a transaction and it calls dao methods which also run int he same transaction. I have tested this code, the transaction indeed beings and rollbacks but the values done rollback.

Comment: By default the annotation causes the aspect to go into the REQUIRED switch. I have tested and debugged this code and its enabling and running in a transaction.

Comment: I'm looking at your `testTransactionMutationRollback()`. It has an entity save() operation. I don't see anything that would weave an aspect around that method. What am I missing?

Comment: This uses spring boot to run and Apring AOP weaves it. the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` weaves the proxy.

Comment: I still don't see what is going to weave a transaction around the `testTransactionMutationRollback()` method.